# Forcefully quit vim even if pattern not found

Tags: vim, command

I am using command `:%s/foo/bar/g | wq` to find and replace using vim. It works fine if pattern is available but if pattern isn't available it `Error detected while processing command line:
E486: Pattern not found: foo`
How can I forcefully exit even if pattern isn't found? I tried `wq!` in above command but didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `substitute` issuing the error. You can set the flag `e`

```
:%s/foo/bar/ge | wq
```

which should prevent the "No match" error from breaking a mapping or commands.

- [`:h :s_flags`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3As_flags)

Answer (score 0):

Every time I tried to exit with :q it gave me an error message "E486: Pattern not found:..."

If I press ":" it appears "?" and instead of :q appeared ?q and gave me the error message: "E486: Pattern not found:..."

Cause? Instead of the US keyboard, I had set the Romanian (Standard) keyboard.
And instead of ":" type "ș" (special Romanian character).
I set back to US keyboard and everything was solved.